# Паттерн делегат

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Если я напишу сервис

```
class UserService {
    private UserRepository repo;  

    public User findUser(id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Будет ли он делегатом?

Comment: Нет не будет - у тебя больше похоже на фасад. Делегату скармливается ф-я. Он оборачивает её вызов.

Comment: вот где та тонкая грань ?  посути Делегат мало где используется ?